# Uncaught Error: Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<UserCredentialJsImpl>', but got one of type 'MemoryInfo'

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, angular-dart

So I'm trying to fix some bugs on a AngularDart legacy app

I think the problem is firebase auth?

here's my code

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as firebase;
 try {
       await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword('email', 'password')
        .then((value) => print('success'));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

But when I try to execute this I get this error

[image]

here are my dependencies

```
Dart VM version: 2.7.1
firebase: 5.0.4
```

**Appreciate any kind of help as I've got no experience in AngularDart
Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. What helped was updating my dart version to `2.10.4` and also updating build_web_compilers in pubspec.yaml to `build_web_compilers: ^2.10.0`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!THANK YOU!!THANK YOU!!THANK YOU!!THANK YOU!!THANK YOU!!